# Vaadin GWT RPC setup?

Tags: gwt, rpc, vaadin

I've been using smartGWT for a few years but have started looking at Vaadin. I've got the example running but am stumped when it comes to writing the RPC call.

I have a connector:

```
public class MyComponent2Connector extends AbstractComponentConnector {
```

And add this to my UI:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Title("StyleSuite Title")
public class MyVaadinUI extends UI
{

    private final MyComponent2Connector c = new MyComponent2Connector();
```

But when I visit the site it says:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com/example/suite_local/client/mycomponent2/MyComponent2Connector

The gwt.xml is very plain and just has:

```
<inherits name="com.vaadin.DefaultWidgetSet" />
```

I'm clearly doing something wrong - anyone have any pointer for setting this up or have an exampe project?

Comment: Do you want to write your own widget, I don't really understand your question

Comment: No. Just an concrete example of how to setup RPC

Comment: Perhaps you can have a look to: https://vaadin.com/web/sami/widget-rpc  and http://dev.vaadin.com/wiki/Vaadin7/RPC and the chapter 16 of the Bokk of Vaadin

Answer (score 1):

Vaadin is a server-side framework, which uses GWT in the client-side to render widgets. Normally you only code serve-side stuff and you don't need to worry about RPC or other communcation between server and client because Vaadin takes care of it under the hood. But if you implement your own widget, then you need RPC (or shared state).

Your problem is that you are trying to use a client-side GWT class (`MyComponent2Connector`) from a server-side class (`MyVaadinUI`), that doesn't work (as you see). [Vaadin 7 mini tutorials](https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Vaadin+7) is good reading and also [Book of Vaadin](https://vaadin.com/book) to understand how Vaadin works.